# How to convert a subdomain to a path with Embedded Tomcat 8 and Spring boot

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

How to rewrite subdomains to paths?

Example:

- **foo.bar** .example.com -->  example.com **/foo/bar**

Or better would be (reverse folders):

- **foo.bar** .example.com -->  example.com **/bar/foo**

Requesting **foo.bar** .example.com should ship a file in /src/main/resources/static/ **bar/foo** /index.html.

With Apache2 it is done by *mod_rewrite*.
I found documentation about rewriting with [Tomcat 8](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) but the question is where to put this files using spring boot?

---

**Update**

I tried using the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), but it seems not possible to define rules in the domain path using regexes substitution.

This is my configuration:

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Java Config to register the Servlet Filter:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean()
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

        registrationBean.setFilter(new UrlRewriteFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("*");
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("confReloadCheckInterval", "5");
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("logLevel", "DEBUG");

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

**urlrewrite.xml** in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Translate</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">foo.bar.example.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">example.com/bar/foo</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

With this **hardcoded** domain it works, but it should work for **every** subdomain like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create you own Filter.

This Filter should:

- check if you have to rewrite your request
- If yes, rewrite URL and URI
- forward request
- it comes again through same filter, but first check will deliver false
- don't forget and be carefull to call `chain.doFilter`

Forwarding will not change any URLs in browser. Just ship content of file.

Follow code could be implementation of such filter. This is not any kind of clean code. Just quick and dirty working code:

```
@Component
public class SubdomainToReversePathFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();

        if (!requestURI.endsWith("/")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            final String servername = req.getServerName();
            final Domain domain = getDomain(servername);

            if (domain.hasSubdomain()) {
                final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = wrapServerName(req, domain);
                wrapped.getRequestDispatcher(requestURI + domain.getSubdomainAsPath()).forward(wrapped, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    private Domain getDomain(final String domain) {
        final String[] domainParts = domain.split("\\.");
        String mainDomain;
        String subDomain = null;

        final int dpLength = domainParts.length;
        if (dpLength > 2) {
            mainDomain = domainParts[dpLength - 2] + "." + domainParts[dpLength - 1];

            subDomain = reverseDomain(domainParts);
        } else {
            mainDomain = domain;
        }

        return new Domain(mainDomain, subDomain);
    }
    private HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapServerName(final HttpServletRequest req, final Domain domain) {
        return new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
            @Override
            public String getServerName() {
                return domain.getMaindomain();
            }
            // more changes? getRequesetURL()? ...?
        };
    }

    private String reverseDomain(final String[] domainParts) {
        final List<String> subdomainList = Arrays.stream(domainParts, 0, domainParts.length - 2)//
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.reverse(subdomainList);

        return subdomainList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("."));
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Here is Domain class:

```
public static class Domain {
    private final String maindomain;
    private final String subdomain;

    public Domain(final String maindomain, final String subdomain) {
        this.maindomain = maindomain;
        this.subdomain = subdomain;
    }

    public String getMaindomain() {
        return maindomain;
    }

    public String getSubdomain() {
        return subdomain;
    }

    public boolean hasSubdomain() {
        return subdomain != null;
    }

    public String getSubdomainAsPath() {
        return "/" + subdomain.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + "/";
    }
}
```

And you need a Controller that catches everything

```
@RestController
public class CatchAllController {

    @RequestMapping("**")
    public FileSystemResource deliver(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String file = ((String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE));

        return new FileSystemResource(getStaticFile(file));
    }

    private File getStaticFile(final String path) {
        try {
            // TODO handle correct
            return new File(CatchAllController.class.getResource("/static/" + path + "/index.html").toURI());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary to override other methods in `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. That's reason for comment.

Also you have to handle cases for file delivery (not existent, ...).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Backreferences` to use grouped parts that matched in your `<condition>`. Something like this -

```
<condition name="host" operator="equal">(*).(*).example.com</condition>
<from>^(.*)</from>
<to type="redirect">example.com/%1/%2</to>
```

Of course, you'll have to tweak the condition rule above to stop eager matching.

More here - http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#condition

Comment: In this case you have hardcoded structure with two parts. This: `mr.foo.bar.example.com -> example.com/bar/foo/mr/` will fail. upvote anyway for short and easy solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this issue: Do it in Controller itself. This is in my opinion better way than with filter because:

- filter catches every request. Here you can better controll which requests should be delivered with 'subdomain pattern'. As example I've choosen `/subdomain2path`.
- You don't have to change/wrap URI/URLs and forward via filter chain again.
- All logic is in this controller

Methods `getSubdomain` and `reverseDomain` are same as in answer before.

This is the impl:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/subdomain2path")
public class Subdomain2PathController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public FileSystemResource deliver(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final Domain subdomain = getSubdomain(request.getServerName());

        String file = "/";
        if (subdomain.hasSubdomain()) {
            file = subdomain.getSubdomainAsPath();
        }

        return new FileSystemResource(getStaticFile(file));
    }

    private Domain getSubdomain(final String domain) {
        final String[] domainParts = domain.split("\\.");
        String mainDomain;
        String subDomain = null;

        final int dpLength = domainParts.length;
        if (dpLength > 2) {
            mainDomain = domainParts[dpLength - 2] + "." + domainParts[dpLength - 1];

            subDomain = reverseDomain(domainParts);
        } else {
            mainDomain = domain;
        }

        return new Domain(mainDomain, subDomain);
    }

    private String reverseDomain(final String[] domainParts) {
        final List<String> subdomainList = Arrays.stream(domainParts, 0, domainParts.length - 2)//
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.reverse(subdomainList);

        return subdomainList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("."));
    }

    private File getStaticFile(final String path) {
        try {
            // TODO handle correct
            return new File(Subdomain2PathController.class.getResource("/static/" + path + "/index.html").toURI());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Domain class is same as in answer before:

```
public static class Domain {
    private final String maindomain;
    private final String subdomain;

    public Domain(final String maindomain, final String subdomain) {
        this.maindomain = maindomain;
        this.subdomain = subdomain;
    }

    public String getMaindomain() {
        return maindomain;
    }

    public String getSubdomain() {
        return subdomain;
    }

    public boolean hasSubdomain() {
        return subdomain != null;
    }

    public String getSubdomainAsPath() {
        return "/" + subdomain.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + "/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### It worked for me. Hope it works for others too.

Please use the following dependency

---

```
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
           <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.4</version>
         </dependency>
```

---

Created urlrewrite.xml in resource folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
<rule>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.userdomain.com</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">http://www.userdomain.com$1</to>
</rule>
```

---

Added in main ApplicationRunner.java

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tuckeyRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomURLRewriter());
    return registrationBean;
}
```

---

And created a CustomURLRewriter

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomURLRewriter extends UrlRewriteFilter {
private UrlRewriter urlRewriter;

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Override
public void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("urlrewrite.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        Conf conf1 = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), inputStream, "urlrewrite.xml", "");
        urlRewriter = new UrlRewriter(conf1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public UrlRewriter getUrlRewriter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    return urlRewriter;
}

@Override
public void destroyUrlRewriter() {
    if(urlRewriter != null)
        urlRewriter.destroy();
}
}
```