# Spring boot cannot find urlrewrite.xml inside jar file

Tags: mod-rewrite, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using Spring Boot with an Embedded Tomcat, and the class UrlRewriteFilter can't find the configuration file urlrewrite.xml, this class uses servletcontext.getResourceAsStream(this.confPath) and I read in other article that this method doesn't work when the package is a jar. Someone had this problem ?

Comment: info about the problem https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3627

Answer (score 4):

Found in [blog post](http://blog.jdriven.com/2016/02/urlrewritefilter-load-configuration-with-spring-resourceloader/)

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;

//Adding @Component Annotation to a Filter is enough to register the Filter, when you have no web.xml
@Component
public class MyUrlRewriteFilter extends UrlRewriteFilter {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "classpath:/urlrewrite.xml";

    //Inject the Resource from the given location
    @Value(CONFIG_LOCATION)
    private Resource resource;

    //Override the loadUrlRewriter method, and write your own implementation
    @Override
    protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        try {
            //Create a UrlRewrite Conf object with the injected resource
            Conf conf = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), resource.getInputStream(), resource.getFilename(), "@@yourOwnSystemId@@");
            checkConf(conf);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ServletException("Unable to load URL rewrite configuration file from " + CONFIG_LOCATION, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me.

Please use the following dependency:

```
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
           <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.4</version>
         </dependency>
```

Create urlrewrite.xml in resource folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.userdomain.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)$</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.userdomain.com$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Add the following in main ApplicationRunner.java:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tuckeyRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomURLRewriter());
    return registrationBean;
}
```

And create a CustomURLRewriter:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;
import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomURLRewriter extends UrlRewriteFilter {
private UrlRewriter urlRewriter;

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Override
public void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("urlrewrite.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        Conf conf1 = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), inputStream, "urlrewrite.xml", "");
        urlRewriter = new UrlRewriter(conf1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public UrlRewriter getUrlRewriter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    return urlRewriter;
}

@Override
public void destroyUrlRewriter() {
    if(urlRewriter != null)
        urlRewriter.destroy();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter with Spring Boot. I followed the initial question implementation in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318439/how-to-convert-a-subdomain-to-a-path-with-embedded-tomcat-8-and-spring-boot) (not the answers).
I also added

```
registrationBean.addInitParameter("confPath", "urlrewrite.xml");
```

to set a specific path for the urlrewrite.xml file.
In the project I put the file in src/main/webapp.

This works when using 'mvn spring-boot:run' which I think meets your need for it to run in a jar. In my project, I build a war file, where this also works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of it, but this worked for me. The library itself uses `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()` at one point to try to resolve the filename, so I think this will work unless the library updates/changes that one day.

```
String fileName = "urlrewrite.xml";
// The prefixed version seems to be needed when running within a jar. 
// Rumor has it that it may be a tomcat 8 specific.
String confPath = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName) != null ? fileName : "/WEB-INF/classes/" + fileName;
registrationBean.addInitParameter("confPath", confPath);
```