# How to convert a subdomain to a path Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

how to configure the application so that each client has its context?

Example:

1. Main

- **client1.**domain.com --> domain.com**/client1**
- **client2.**domain.com --> domain.com**/client2**
- ....

2. Login

- **client1.**domain.com**/Login** --> domain.com**/client1/Login**
- **client2.**domain.com**/Login** --> domain.com**/client2/Login**
- ....

My current application uses the configuration of subdomains because springboot itself identifies that it is in different contexts, but I can't understand how to do this through the path

Comment: not sure if you are looking for path like domain.com/client/1 which should return client 1 data. You can check this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start and search for following method:  @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Book findOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id)
          .orElseThrow(BookNotFoundException::new);
    }

Comment: @Rakmo thanks for the reply, i actually need the application to have an independent context for each tenant based on the first subdirectory of uri.
for example:
mydomain.com/tenant1/*
mydomain.com/tenant2/*
where the * would be all consumption urls

Comment: This is not available out of the box. If your URL structure is identical for each client, you could do something clever with a custom argument resolver.

Comment: Any reason you can't do this in DNS records? Or use a LoadBalancer to route to the right endpoint on your server?

Comment: @YashDigantJoshi Thanks for the answer. Currently the system is developed exactly as you described, but this idea of ​​modification has the principle of reducing costs

Comment: Ah got it. Just thinking more about it. You could use a custom filter to handle the requests. Here is an example of how you can get this to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318439/how-to-convert-a-subdomain-to-a-path-with-embedded-tomcat-8-and-spring-boot

Comment: @YashDigantJoshi 
thanks for the idea mentioned in the link, after some testing we found that we would have to make a lot of changes for the system to work and we abandoned this idea. even so thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the hostname form the request using  annotation:

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/secret")
  @ResponseBody public String getSecret(@RequestHeader("Host") String host ) {
    var client = getClientFromHost(host);
    // ...
  }
```

If there is a load balancer in front of this service, you can use the `X-Forwarded-From` header instead of the `Host` header.

And then you could simply parse the host URL, to extract the subdomain which identifies your client.